# Reading data from Oracle storage cloud to external table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Hi I have csv file in object storage in `Oracle cloud`. I want to store this data in the `external table` which is outside the cloud.can anybody guide me on the same?
 How can I read the data from cloud and store in table? I am using Oracle gen2 cloud.

Comment: Please refer the article doing exactly what you want https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/loading-your-object-store-data-into-autonomous-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dbms_cloud is the solution for the above issue.